# Numeric Citation for Compiled Thesis using Kile

Tags: citing, kile

I am in the process of writing and compiling my Ph.D. Thesis. I have to arrange my references using `bibtex` and the format to be followed is the one followed by Physical Review Special Topics: Physics Education Research i.e. `revtex4-1` and `apsrev4-1`. The problem is that if I am compiling a single file, the citations are numeric, but when I am combining the files and using the document class of report, the citations are taking the author year form. Kindly help as I need numeric citations precisely according
to `revtex4-1` and `apsrev4-1` ... Here is the MWE. Firstly, given is the Single file named 2Basked1.tex

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,preprint,groupedaddress]{revtex4-1}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}                                            
\usepackage{array}                                            
\usepackage{longtable}                                        
\usepackage{calc}                                             
\usepackage{multirow}                                         
\usepackage{hhline}                                           
\usepackage{ifthen}  
%\usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{makecell}

 \title{Chapter:\textbf{Introduction}}
 %\author{}
\def\inputGnumericTable{} 
\begin{document}
\cite{wiki:PER}sometext
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1} 
\bibliography{thesis1}
 \end{document}
```

Now the file to be included in the compiled form is as follows:
name of the file: **2Basked2.tex**

```
\title{Chapter:\textbf{Introduction}}
\cite{wiki:PER}sometext
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1} 
\bibliography{thesis1}
```

ow given is the compiled form of the thesis named **compiledForm.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openbib]{report} 
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
   \usepackage{array}                                                 %%
\usepackage{calc}                                             %%
\usepackage{multirow}                                         %%
\usepackage{hhline}                                           %%
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
\date{}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
 \newcommand{\Ann}{\mbox{Ann}}
%-------------------------
\textheight=9in \textwidth=6.15in
%---------------------------
%\textheight=220mm \textwidth=160mm
%---------------------------------
\leftmargin 25mm  \rightmargin 35mm
%------------------------------------
%\leftmargin 35mm \rightmargin 25mm
\topmargin 0mm \oddsidemargin 15mm
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{10}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
 \parindent 9mm \parskip 12pt

 \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \listoffigures
 \listoftables
 \input{2Basked2}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following inclusions in compiledForm.tex, have done the job

```
     \usepackage{natbib}
     \setcitestyle{numbers,square}
```

Comment: but now I am getting overlapping/repeated bibliography instead of individual ones, at the end of the chapters included in compiledForm.tex